# Avalondock close document with MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro, avalondock

We have a working avalondock implementation that listens to onclosing events, if the document is not saved the user gets a chance to save it etc. Works well.

Now a user wants a close button from the File menu and it should work like the built in close button (The little X by the document name).

Only way I have find is not very MVVM friendly.

I databind the CloseCommand to the dockable items ViewModel like

```
<Setter Property="CloseCommand" Value="{ Binding Model.CloseCommand, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Then from the ViewModel i have a method

```
public ICommand CloseCommand { get; set; }

public void Close()
{
    if (CloseCommand.CanExecute(this))
    {
        CloseCommand.Execute(this);
    }
}
```

This works and all the behaviour from pressing the built in close button is retained. But I think its a ugly hack. I'm dependant on that the View databinds the CloseCommand down to the viewmodel etc. There must be a more MVVM way of triggering close?

Comment: Do you want to use `caliburn.micro` or...?

Comment: Well, I want to sue a more MVVM way. Databind a command on the model and then execute said command from model feels backward

Comment: While closing, to you call `TryClose()` method from cm?

Comment: Avalondock does not support that

Comment: A avalockdock panel inherits PropertyChangeBase, which CM Screen does too. But calling TryClose does nothing

Comment: When you want to open a new tab/window... do you use `ActivateItem()`? Try overriding `TryClose` and chekc what happens... the method asks Parrent (if it exists, if not it closes app) if there is active child and then it closes it...

Comment: I just add the viewmodel to a list databound to DokingManager. DocumentsSource

Comment: Do you have any sample of your situation, to upload the code on git, so I can try?

Comment: Yeah, sure, the code is open source https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/FreePIE/blob/master/FreePIE.GUI/Views/Main/PanelViewModel.cs#L91

Comment: Inside MainShellView.xaml in `DockingManager`
 add this line 
`cal:Message.Attach="[Event DocumentClosing]=[Action CloseMe($eventargs)]" `
It should look like this...
`<xcad:DockingManager cal:Message.Attach="[Event DocumentClosing]=[Action CloseMe($eventargs)]".......`
And inside MainShellViewModel.cs add method  `public void CloseMe(object ob){}`
Now what happens... when your document starts to close this method will automatically get called.
There is no need for `ICommand` then...

Comment: We already use the document closing and document closed events. To use them from code behind is offcourse a option. But you would need to reproduce the cancel code etc that avalon has yourself

Comment: Well I don't see any other way... I'm always trying to bypass code-behind when using MVVM

Comment: How do you bind to your Model in the LayoutItem? I cant set the DataConetxt

Comment: @laserman https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/FreePIE/blob/b7ead60f4bc6fbe492adb111c4dfa542a644dd37/FreePIE.GUI/Shells/MainShellView.xaml#L49

Comment: I get: System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'DocumentCloseCommand' property not found on 'object' ''LayoutAnchorableItem' (Name='')'. BindingExpression:Path=DocumentCloseCommand; DataItem='LayoutAnchorableItem' (Name=''); target element is 'LayoutAnchorableItem' (Name=''); target property is 'CloseCommand' (type 'ICommand')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it like this

VM

```
public ICommand CloseCommand { get; set; }

public void Close()
{
    if (CloseCommand.CanExecute(this))
    {
        CloseCommand.Execute(this);
    }
}
```

View

```
<xcad:DockingManager.LayoutItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type xcad:LayoutItem}">
        <Setter Property="Title" Value="{Binding Model.Title}" />
        <Setter Property="IconSource" Value="{Binding Model.Icon}"/>
        <Setter Property="IsActive" Value="{Binding Model.IsActive, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        <Setter Property="ContentId" Value="{Binding Model.ContentId}"/>
        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="{Binding Model.IsVisible, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static Visibility.Hidden}}"/>
        <Setter Property="CloseCommand" Value="{ Binding Model.CloseCommand, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    </Style>
</xcad:DockingManager.LayoutItemContainerStyle>
```